# Stage status is marked as "aborted" though the stage is not even executed

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

My pipeline looks something like this...

```
@Library('sharedLib')_
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            steps {
                //code
            }
        }
        stage('checklist') {
            parallel {
                stage('sonar Linters') {
                    steps {
                        script{
                           //code
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('validate merge request') {
                    steps {
                        //code
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    //code
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage("Automation Test") {
            parallel {
                    
                    stage('Unit Test') {
                    stages {
                    
            stage ('JUnit') {
              
                steps {
                    script {                            
                        //code
                    }                    
                }
            }

                    
            stage ('Mutation Coverage Report') {
               
            options {
            timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')
            retry(2)
            
            }
                steps {
                    script {
                        //code
                    }
                }                            
               
            }
 
                    } }  
                    
            stage ("Impact Analysis Report") {
             
            options {
            timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES')
            
            
            }
                steps {
                    script { 
                   //code
                    }
                }
            }

                                                        
                    }
        } 
        
     
        
    }
}
```

Here,I have used shared libraries to store stage wise execution files. When the "build" stage fails, the "junit" stage status is set as "Aborted" in /wfapi/describe jenkins API. The junit stage has a file with try catch block to be executed.. Is that the reason causing this or Is this an jenkins issue? How do I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the `try-catch` block to make sure that the error handling and reporting are done correctly during the `junit` stage. Make sure that any exceptions are detected and properly logged.

**Prevent Error Impact:** Verify that mistakes made during the "build" stage do not have an impact on later phases, particularly `junit.` Maintaining the pipeline's anticipated flow may depend on this.

**Apply Conditional Execution:** Conditionally execute the `junit` step according to the results of the 'build' stage by using the when directive. This aids in managing the flow of execution.

**Update Jenkins:** Make sure you are using the latest version of Jenkins. Bug fixes and enhancements that may resolve unexpected behaviors are frequently included in updates.